# Internal Server Error in Careers when "adding an answer"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Adding any answer from stack exchange to Careers causes `Internal Server Error`

this is the ajax address causing the problem:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/widgets/stackexchangeanswers/findAnswerFromLink?link=[link to stackoverflow answer]
```

Comment: I see your collection of errors in the log, I'll get this fixed and let you know when it's ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix is on it's way through the pipe.  This was a null reference error.  The answer finder we use is still based on API v1 and we track users with account ids now instead of the old way.  It's on the list to update the answer widget to API v2 soon.